# Using M query to extract an un-named range from multiple excel files?

Tags: powerbi, m

The M query code below extracts a range of rows from a sheet called "Survey Information" in an excel file called Paris. - But what if I wish to do this not just for a single excel file, but for ***all*** of the excel files located in Folder1 (Berlin, Milan, etc.)? (Whilst each excel file would contain multiple sheets, each file would have a single sheet called "Survey Information".)

Unfortunately there are no named ranges. I have a large number of excel files to pull the data out of.

Very grateful for any insight,

Chris

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Q:\Folder1\Paris.xls"), null, true),
#"Survey Information1" = Source{[Name="Survey Information"]}[Data],
#"Kept Range of Rows" = Table.Range(#"Survey Information1",19,14) in
#"Kept Range of Rows"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. How about listing all files in a given folder, iterate over the result set and execute your given code for all `*.xls` files?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed my question. - How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer to my own question. - I need to turn the code into a function by prefixing it with (filepath)=>

I found a step-by-step guide here:
https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/02/25/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-in-power-query/

All the best.